# Want to send a specific row of excel to dataprovider in selenium TestNG

Tags: excel, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have created an excel of 10 rows×10 columns.I want dataprovider to return only those rows,which has a value "Y" in the respective column.This will be used when a Test suite will be executed and test cases to be executed will be flagged as "Y".

Need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Please find my code below.:
......................................

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testdata")

public void Create(String TC_ID, String TC_Name, String Username, String Password, String aaa, String bbb, String ccc, String ddd, String eee, String fff, String ggg, String hhh, String iii, String jjj, String kkk, String lll) throws InterruptedException {

　

if (lll.equals("Y")) {

} else {

System.out.println("Testcases not flagged for Automation.." + "......." + TC_ID + "...." + TC_Name);

throw new SkipException("...Skipped....");

}

}

//  @AfterMethod

//

//  public void tearDown() {

//  driver.quit();

//  }


@DataProvider(name = "testdata")

public String[][] readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException {

File f = new File("C:/Test input/Test.xls");

Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);

Sheet s = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

int rows = s.getRows();

int columns = s.getColumns();

//  System.out.println(rows);

//  System.out.println(columns);


String inputData[][] = new String[rows - 1][columns];

for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {

for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

Cell c = s.getCell(j, i);

inputData[i - 1][j] = c.getContents();

　}

}
return inputData;

}

}
```

......................................
I want to add a column to my excel test data,where the flag(Y/N) will be mentioned.Only Y flagged test cases will be executed.
But here in my code Y flagged tcases are getting executed and others are getting skipped and those skipped testcases are also getting added to the testng report which I dont want.

Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the test code you have so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: Added my code..

Comment: I have made a small attempt at tidying up the code but please indent it properly and maybe further improve spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this you can update your code in DataProvider itself that it should return only those columns where you have Y in last column.
This will help and you won't find them in test report.